# Populate hash of hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, populate, perl-data-structures

I want to know how to populate the following hash structure:

```
my $hash = {
    'user' => [
        {
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'John'
        },
        {
            'id' => '2',
            'name' => 'Pat'
        }

    ]
};
```

I want to be able to dynamically populate this hash.  I want to loop around values from my database and push (add) new values (id, name) in order to populate the hash.

Comment: @Benoit: Wrong, actually, he is using an anonymous hash reference. He could use `my %hash = (...);`

Comment: What exactly do the values from your database look like? Most data layer APIs already return the data in **precisely** this format so you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to populate a value in a hash of hashes, one can just use :

```
my %hash;
....
$hash{$key}{$subkey} = $value;
```

Be careful when you loop through them, however!  The scalar value `$hash{$key}` will actually be a scalar *reference* to the sub-hash, not the sub-hash object itself.

Comment: He's using a hash reference, so it should be `$hash->{$hey}{$subkey} = $value;`

Comment: fair enough, I honestly assumed he meant `%hash` myself :)

Comment: Thanks Platinum Azure and asf107.  
Since I'm populating this hash dynamically, how to I add new values ? Here's my code.  As you can see, this won't work because the previous value will always get overwritten.
 foreach my $user (@users) {
  $hash->{user}{id} = $user[0];
  $hash->{user}{name} = $user[1];

 } 
Thanks

Comment: How is `@users` populated? is it a anon array or values? If its values, you will need to use a while loop or for loop where you control the stepping.  Is it `@users = ('John',1,'Pat',2)` or `@users = (['John',1],['Pat',2])`  ?

Comment: the code `foreach my $user (@users)` will simply give you a loop where, in each iteration, the variable `$user` will take the scalar value `$users[0], $users[1], ... ` etc.  What type of data is `$user[0]` ?

Answer (score 3):

To add another element to that structure:

```
# Get the element
my $hashRef = {
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'John'
};
# You didn't specify what you have as far as DB data
my $hashRef = someMethodReturningDatabaseData(); 

# Add to the arrayref:
my $hash = { user => [] }; # Initialize - only once
$hash->{user} ||= []; # As alternative, always make sure to have an arrayref,
                      # on every iteration
# Add to the array ref
push @{ $hash->{user} }, $hashRef;
```

Based on your comment to another answer, you can do

```
my $hash = { user => [] }; # Initialize - only once
foreach my $user (@users) {
    push @{ $hash->{user} }, { id => $user->[0], name => $user->[1] };
}
```

As a note, your data structure looks very weird - it's not clear why you need the outer hash with just one hard-coded key "`user`".

Comment: +1 for `||=`. On a side note, as of Perl 5.14, dereferencing the array ref is not necessary anymore (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html).

Comment: @Martin, Maybe, but it's experimental, and has bugs (doesn't work on all arrays, doesn't autovivify).

Comment: You need to change `$user->[0]` and `$user->[1]` .When I tested it earlier, I thought it was a new feature. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    my $user = {
        id   => $id,
        name => $name,
    };

    push @{ $hash->{user} }, $user;
```

---

Nit: `$hash->{user}` should be named `$hash->{users}`